# How to use SVG images in c++/winrt UWP application?

Tags: c++, svg, uwp, c++-winrt

I have been able to programmatically display bitmap images using C++/WinRT in my UWP applications, however I can't get SVG images to work.

Below is the most simple example I could come up with. I create an application, I load an SVG image, I add it to the application window and activate the window. I have provided the source code and the SVG file below.

A few notes:

- The application runs, it's just that no image is displayed
- I made sure the SVG file is compliant with [supported features in Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt790715%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- The file is in my project root folder
- Loading bitmaps in a similar way works without problems
- I have tried to troubleshoot using the OpenFailed method, but the info it gives is useless

---

#### source

```
#include "pch.h"


using namespace winrt;
using namespace winrt::Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging;


struct App : ApplicationT<App>
{
    Image mImage;

    void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs const &)
    {
        //Load PNG image - WORKS
        //mImage.Source(BitmapImage(Uri(L"ms-appx:///sample.png")));

        //Load SVG image - FAILS
        mImage.Source(SvgImageSource(Uri(L"ms-appx:///sample.svg")));
        
        //Show image on screen
        Window window = Window::Current();
        window.Content(mImage);
        window.Activate();
    }

    static void Init(ApplicationInitializationCallbackParams const &)
    {
        make<App>();
    }
};

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, PWSTR, int)
{
    Application::Start(App::Init);
}
```

---

#### sample.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg width="100" height="100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in your code, but in the fact that the file is not copied with the app content.

Click on the `sample.svg` file in the Solution Explorer and look into the **Properties** toolbar. You will see `Content` set as `False`. You need to set it to `True` so that the file is copied into the output folder along with other content files like images (those are `Content` by default, so that is why you don't have to do this).

[image: Content setting]

Comment: This was what needed to be done. I find application resources a not well documented nor easy to find topic on the Windows developer pages. This helped a lot.

Comment: Glad it helped :-). Happy coding!